# Check brackets for balancing, using stack in python

Tags: python, arrays, stack

I'm solving such issue:
I need to implement a feature for a string to find errors in the usage of brackets.
If string is balanced, then I should return

```
{}    
Success
```

If not, I need to mention the position of problematic bracket.

```
{[}
3
```

So for that reason I decided to create a class Bracket

```
class Bracket:
    def __init__(self, bracket_type, position):
        self.bracket_type = bracket_type
        self.position = position

    def Match(self, c):
        if self.bracket_type == '[' and c == ']':
            return True
        if self.bracket_type == '{' and c == '}':
            return True
        if self.bracket_type == '(' and c == ')':
            return True
        return False
```

Next, I'm using stack, whether sting is balanced or not. I created a loop, going through every symbol, and if symbol is a bracket I want to assign it to my special class in order to match for closing one further.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    text = sys.stdin.read()

    brackets_stack = []
    Balanced = True


    for i, symbol in enumerate(str(text)):
        if symbol in ['(', '[', '{']:
            j = i
            brackets_stack.append(symbol)
            new_bracket = Bracket(brackets_stack[j], j)

        elif new_bracket.Match(symbol) == True:
            brackets_stack.pop(i)

        elif len(brackets_stack) == 0:
            print("Success")
```

But it works good only with cases like this

```
{}    
Success
```

For other tests, like

```
[()]
```

It shows that array is not empty yet, as his tenth is equal to 1. I think the problem lies in variable new_bracket. After removing "(" from array my program doesn't compare "{" for matching.

I don't know why.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: The last bit should not be inside a loop, because the input `()[` will print 'Success' since the stack will be empty after `)`. Put it *after* the loop.

Comment: I think the problem is slightly more complex if you are allowed to have asymmetrical but balanced brackets e.g. ( [ { } ( ) ]  ( ) ) . Something to consider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has a few problems. First, there are a few things that I want to address:

1. Your code will throw an error if the symbols string does not start with an opening bracket. This is because you initialize `new_bracket` inside of the first if statement. This would cause problems since if the first character is NOT an opening bracket, it will try to call `new_bracket` in the elif statement, and since it has not been initiated, it will raise an `UnboundLocalError`. This can be fixed with an `elif symbol in [')', ']', '}']: return False`. Since starting with a close bracket obviously means its unbalanced, this makes sense and prevents the program from calling `new_bracket` without it being initialized.
2. Your use of the `j` variable is useless since you never use it outside of the scope of that if statement. You could have just used `i`.
3. Your use of `list.pop(i)` may cause errors if `i` is out of range of `brackets_stack`. You don't need the index since you want the symbol at the end of the stack, which is automatically what `list.pop()` does.
4. `elif len(brackets_stack) == 0:` should not be inside of the for loop. This should be outside of the loop since you only want to say success after all the text has been processed.
5. `new_bracket = Bracket(brackets_stack[j], j)` is wrong in many ways. The first is that you don't want to make a new symbol with `brackets_stack[j]`, you want it to be made with either `text[j]` or better yet, `symbol`. Another is that this will only be changed whenever a new open bracket is seen. However, if you find the match to that bracket, since you never change this variable, it will stay as the previous bracket. You should re-declare what the symbol of your `new_bracket` should be. The name itself is then misleading and is changed below.

With all this in mind, below is a revised version of what you want to do, encapsulated in a function. There are some stuff you need to add to your class as well.

```
class Bracket:
    def __init__(self, bracket_type, position):
        self.bracket_type = bracket_type
        self.position = position

    def Match(self, c):
        if self.bracket_type: //handles empty bracket_type
            if self.bracket_type == '[' and c == ']':
                return True
            if self.bracket_type == '{' and c == '}':
                return True
            if self.bracket_type == '(' and c == ')':
                return True
        return False

    //update function to use the same object instead of initializing a new one each time (better space complexity)
    def update(self, new_type, new_position):
        self.bracket_type = new_type
        self.position = new_position

// pass in text to check if text has balanced brackets or not
def isBalanced(text):
     brackets_stack = []
     current_bracket = Bracket('',0) //initialize an empty bracket
     for i, symbol in enumerate(str(text)):
         print(brackets_stack)
         if symbol in ['(', '[', '{']:
                 brackets_stack.append(symbol)
                 current_bracket.update(symbol, i) //call update function
         elif symbol in [')', ']', '}']:
             return False
         elif new_bracket.Match(symbol):
             brackets_stack.pop()
         else: //since it assumes symmetrical balanced brackets, this can return False immediately
             return False
//same as saying return len(list) == 0
     return not(len(brackets_stack))
```

This code assumes that `text` ONLY contains brackets. I do not know if this is a reasonable assumption and you should keep this in mind for whatever application you are using it for. Also, like MTset commented on your post, it also assumes simply, symmetrical, balanced brackets. `[{]}` will return False, although it is technically balanced.